# On GNOME, make the current window take the whole screen

Tags: shell-script, gnome3

I am looking for a way to cause the current window on GNOME 3 to take the whole screen. It should be in a form of a script, not a Qt or Python application.

I have installed and tried `xdotool` but it is not working for me either with the `windowsize` option or even by using the <kbd>F11</kbd> key (pressing it on many systems will have the desired effect). Only help works.

Comment: Are you on xorg or wayland?

Comment: Default Gnome keyboard shortcut for this is meta (windows) key + up arrow

Answer (score 1):

> `wmctrl` is a UNIX/Linux command line tool to interact with an EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager

[Link](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) to homepage (see `Tips`) if not already in your distribution.

For example,

```shell
wmctrl -r firefox -b toggle,fullscreen
```